# cygwin fork error

Tags: cygwin

I have set up a new PC and installed cygwin on it.
Its windows 7 pro.

Whenever I try to build our application on it, I get the following error:

```
 0 [main] sh 3472 child_info_fork::abort: can't commit memory for stack 0x28A000(90112), Win32 error 487

/bin/sh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
      0 [main] sh 3220 child_info_fork::abort: can't commit memory for stack 0x28A000(90112), Win32 error 487

/bin/sh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
      0 [main] sh 4896 child_info_fork::abort: can't commit memory for stack 0x28A000(90112), Win32 error 487

/bin/sh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
      0 [main] sh 4884 child_info_fork::abort: can't commit memory for stack 0x28A000(90112), Win32 error 487
```

It prints this few times and then dies.

I have already done a lot of research on this problem.
I have already uninstalled and installed cygwin  more than 5 times.
Done rebaseall everytime I installed it.
Checked for possible BLODA, I had notron antivirus, which I have removed.

As an aside, I tried posting this question to cygwin mailing list after subscribing to it. But my mail does not appear on the list. I suppose they want address to be munged and I have no clue how to do it. supposedly, they are treating it as a spam.
Any idea how I can post to the mailing list there.

Comment: I am not able to put output of cygcheck and rebase as it becomes very big. Also, if i try to snip it, it does not accept it saying not proper formatting. I think i cant attach anything in stack overflow, so not sure what to do?

Comment: The most likely reason for your email being rejected from the Cygwin mailing list is that it's not in plain text. How to fix that depends on your mail client, but Googling for "{mail client} plain text email" will help.

Comment: For large output files dumps, your best bet is to dump them onto your favourite online pastebin, then link to them.

Comment: @ me_and: thanks for tip about cygwin mailing list, atleast I am now able to post my query there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when building the application and the problem was that the path to the project was too long:

```
C:\Nabil\CXXXX\SCRs\XXXXX_Fix_the_unconnected_XXX_operations\XXXXX_HXXT~Nabil_XXX.01.00_XXX.01.05_oldXXXedit\CAXXX_HXXT\Applications
```

The issue was solved when I changed the path to be:

```
C:\XXXXX_HXXT~Nabil_XXX.01.00_XXX.01.05_oldXXXedit\CAXXX_HXXT\Applications
```